# Split a list into multiple sequential files

Tags: python, text-processing

I have a file of more than 2000 jokes that I've done some preprocessing on and now have them in a list. I want to print them so that there are 20 per text document (except for the last document which may have fewer) and that they are numbered sequentially (jokeset1.txt, jokeset2.txt, etc), but when I try to do something like this, it only creates the first and last documents. How can I fix this?

```
i = 0
while len(jokes)>0:
    i+=1
    with open('Jokeset/jokeset' + str(i)+'.txt', 'w') as newfile:
        if len(jokes)<20:
            x = len(jokes)
        else:
            x = 20
        random.shuffle(jokes)
        for i in range(x):
            print(jokes[i], file = newfile)
        del jokes[:x]
```

Comment: You use `i` in two different places : for the number of the file and in the for loop. Change one of the names. More generally, you would avoid such mistakes by giving your variables meaningful names. `set_number` would be better than `i`...

Answer (score 1):

You're rewriting your `i` variable inside of the loop!

You have `i = 1` for the first run of the loop, so the first file is written, but then when you do

```py
for i in range(x):
    print(jokes[i], file = newfile)
```

the variable becomes `i = 19`. Then you just do `i += 1` at the start of the outer loop and you're writing to a file called `'Jokeset/jokeset20.txt'`. And this keeps happening over and over again, so no other files ever get written.

Simply rename one of your `i` variables and you will be good!

Comment: Oh such a simple mistake! Thanks for the suggestion!